# Remove Character and 2 trailing Wildcards from anywhere in String

Tags: mysql, sql, string, case, wildcard

**SCENARIO:**

I need to remove every instance of '-' along with the two following characters (wildcards) from strings of undetermined lengths.

The context is that a user can select a State and the Counties in that State. The database structure of the system I am using prevents me from using repeat values for the Counties with different parents, so BARBOUR county in Alaska is named BARBOUR-AL in order to account for all of the duplicate county names.

When the user selected counties are outputted in a report I see this:

```
+-----------------------+
|       Targeting       |
+-----------------------+
| BARBOUR-AL,BALDWIN-AL |
+-----------------------+
```

How can I achieve the following output with the knowledge that the State abbreviations are wildcards?

Here is the current state of the query and the desired output. target_counties is the column I need to remove the string segments from.

**CURRENT QUERY SEGMENT:**

This is part of a larger query where several columns are selected.

```
CASE
  WHEN targeting_type = 'County' THEN target_counties /* MODIFY HERE */
  ELSE target_msa
END AS 'Targeting',
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
+-----------------------+
|       Targeting       |
+-----------------------+
|    BARBOUR,BALDWIN    |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Fix your data structure so you are not storing lists of things in a single field.  You should have another table, with one row per whatever and county.

Comment: Also, any time you want fancy / verbose code easily accessible to a query, just write an SQL FUNCTION and call that from your query.  PS - Here's one way to "split()" strings in MySQL: https://coderwall.com/p/zzgo-w/splitting-strings-with-mysql

Comment: I don't have the ability to do the above. I am reporting on a DB that is integrated in SaaS system. All I can do is query the information and setup simple structures/objects. In this scenario I have a structure with States, and the Counties are in a substructure linked to their parent states (thus the state suffix to handle duplicate). The is only other way to handle this would be to setup a unique structure for each state which is just silly, but it would still be lists stored in a single field. Guess we'll just have to deal, thanks for the information!